# Install a specific version of Docker CE on Amazon EC2 Linux

Tags: linux, docker, amazon-ec2, yum

Due to a recent [vulnerability](https://seclists.org/oss-sec/2019/q1/119) with Docker CE I need to update our fleet of EC2 instances running Amazon Linux base AMI to the latest version. How do I install a specific version of Docker CE for Amazon Linux?

Answer (score 0):

[AWS has updated their docker package](https://alas.aws.amazon.com/ALAS-2019-1156.html) to handle this vulnerability. Run `sudo yum update -y docker` and then restart docker `service docker restart`.